I am trying to build maven project but it cannot access internet. What should I do?
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/146.75.112.215, repo.maven.apache.org/2a04:4e42:8c:0:0:0:0:215] failed: Connect timed out
I tried mvn clean install -U.
I tried other commands also but everthing fails. Please help how can I get access of Internet

You seemd to be behind a firewall/proxy etc.

Talk to your network administrator
